# How to change resources namespace

Tags: asp.net-mvc, namespaces, resource-files

I want to change the namespace of the resources in my mvc application.

The file I change is generated, so as soon as I alter a resource value, it resets back to the default (Resources).

How can I change it so that when the file is generated, it uses my alternative namespace?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your detail is lacking so I assume you are working with visual studio and using embedded resources and you were trying to directly change the generated code.

- Right click on the .resx file and click *Properties*
- Fill in a namespace in field *Custom Tool Namespace*

This namespace should now be used the next time your resource file auto generates the code-behind file.